# iOS XMPP received message in conversation screen

Tags: ios, xmpp

I am working on XMPP based project. I am able to send message and it displays in conversation screen but when I receive message it only show in alertview not able to see in conversation screen.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(messageReceived:) name:MessageRecivedNotif object:nil];

appdelegate=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[self getAllMessagesArrayWithOppositeUser:_jid];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];


}

#pragma mark table delegate and datasource methods
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return data.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tblobj dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
UILabel *lbl;
if (cell==nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (chatLblRight == 1)
    {
        lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 10, 150, 44)];
        [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [cell.contentView   addSubview:lbl];
    }


 }
 if (chatLblRight == 1)
 {
    lbl.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"text"];
    chatLblRight = 0;
    lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 10, 150, 44)];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [cell.contentView   addSubview:lbl];

    return cell;
  }
  else
  {
    cell.textLabel.text=[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"text"];
    return cell;
  }
}
-(void)messageReceived:(NSNotification*)notif
{
XMPPMessage *message=(XMPPMessage*)notif.object;
NSString *body = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
NSMutableDictionary *dic_recive = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dic_recive setObject:body forKey:@"text"];
[data addObject:dic_recive];
chatLblRight = 1;
[tblobj reloadData];
}
 -(IBAction)btnsend:(id)sender
{
[txtmsg resignFirstResponder];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
[msgview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-53, self.view.bounds.size.width, 53)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]) sendMessage:txtmsg.text toUserWithJid:_jid];
NSMutableDictionary *dic_send = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dic_send setObject:txtmsg.text forKey:@"text"];
[data addObject:dic_send];
[tblobj reloadData];
txtmsg.text=@"";
 }
-(NSMutableArray *)getAllMessagesArrayWithOppositeUser:(XMPPJID *)xmppUser
{
XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage *storage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [storage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject"
                                                     inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
NSError *error;
NSArray *messages = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

data=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

@autoreleasepool {
    for (XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject *message in messages) {

        if ([message.bareJid isEqual:xmppUser])
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [dict setObject:message.body forKey:@"text"];
            [dict setObject:message.timestamp forKey:@"date"];
            if ([message isOutgoing]) {
                [dict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"type"];
                [dict setObject:[[message.bareJidStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"] firstObject] forKey:@"username"];
                [dict setObject:[UIColor greenColor] forKey:@"color"];
            }
            else{

                [dict setObject:@"2" forKey:@"type"];
                [dict setObject:[[message.bareJidStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"] firstObject] forKey:@"username"];
                //                    [dict setObject:userName forKey:@"username"];
                [dict setObject:[UIColor blueColor] forKey:@"color"];
             }
            [data addObject:dict];
          }
      }
  }

   return data;
}
```

Where is my mistake ?

**EDIT**

```
 - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{

DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);


if ([message isChatMessageWithBody])
{
    XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage *xmppMessageStorage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
    XMPPMessageArchiving *xmppMessageArchiving = [[XMPPMessageArchiving alloc] initWithMessageArchivingStorage:xmppMessageStorage];

    [xmppMessageArchiving activate:xmppStream];
    [xmppMessageArchiving addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [xmppRosterStorage userForJID:[message from]
                                                             xmppStream:xmppStream
                                                   managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext_roster]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:MessageRecivedNotif object:message];

    NSString *body = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
    NSString *displayName = [user displayName];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:displayName
                                                            message:body
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    else
    {
        // We are not active, so use a local notification instead
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.alertAction = @"Ok";
        localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From: %@\n\n%@",displayName,body];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have u find any solution then tell me i am also making chat app with xmpp and now working on how to display received message in tableview...please help me

Comment: yes i have done write on anand acharya's answer .

Comment: ok i will try..thanks... have u done any changes in did receive message in appdelegate

Comment: No i didn,t change anything in this method.

Comment: I didn' get it...can u please share your .h and .m file with me

Comment: i will send you today knight . give me your mail id .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90226/discussion-between-bhavin-ramani-and-badal-shah).

Comment: I have give u my email id..have u got it?

Comment: thanks a lot..... @Badal Shah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set your logic in uitableviewcellforrowatindexpath method like this.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tblobj dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
UILabel *lbl;
if (cell==nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if([[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"2"])
    //if (chatLblRight == 1)
    {
        lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 10, 150, 44)];
        [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [cell.contentView   addSubview:lbl];
    }


}
if([[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"2"])

//if([[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
//if (chatLblRight == 1)
{
    lbl.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"text"];
    chatLblRight = 0;
    lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 10, 150, 44)];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [cell.contentView   addSubview:lbl];

    return cell;
}
else
{
    cell.textLabel.text=[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"text"];
    return cell;
  }

}
```

please check this code once.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage*)message
{
//in this the (XMPPMessage*)message parameter is xml data
//parse you xml and create dictionary For eg : sampledict
}
```

Normally when you are getting reply from XMPP it comes like XML data. That you have to parse and use for your operations.

And in your code here

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive)
{
   // UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:displayName
                                                        message:body
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
   // [alertView show];
}
else
{
    // We are not active, so use a local notification instead
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.alertAction = @"Ok";
    localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From: %@\n\n%@",displayName,body];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
}
```

You have used alertview. So you have to hide your alertview so that you don't get alerts. Instead manage your observer method to get data and use it

```
-(void)messageReceived:(NSNotification*)notif
{ 
XMPPMessage *message=(XMPPMessage*)notif.object;
NSString *body = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
NSMutableDictionary *dic_recive = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dic_recive setObject:body forKey:@"text"];
[data addObject:dic_recive];
chatLblRight = 1;
[tblobj reloadData];
}
```

I think this will help you..

Comment: thanks for replay. you deserve up voting for help. where i have to write 1st code? in app delegate.m or my chatconversionview controller?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to xmpp custom class and post a notification like this

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{
//parse you xml and create dictionary For eg : sampledict
NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
                        [notificationCenter postNotificationName:@"updateValue" object:nil userInfo:sampledict];

}
```

and receive notification from your class like
using notification like

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(receiveUpdatedValues:)
                                                 name:@"updateValue"
                                               object:nil];


-(void)receiveUpdatedValues : (NSNotification *)notification
{
NSDictionary *dictinfo=notification.userInfo;
// here use your info dict to get your message
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay. what is sampledict and where i have to declare it? currently i edited my `- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message` method. [lease guide me. thanks.