# How to show received message in tableview in xmpp

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xmppframework

i am making a chat app with xmpp framework.

I have setup XMPPFramework in my project by referring this link:- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-setup--mobile-7190

In this message sending is working perfectly and in receive message it is show in alertview as it is in code. When message received this method is calling which is in Appdelegate.m file:-

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
// A simple example of inbound message handling.

if ([message isChatMessageWithBody])
{
    XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [xmppRosterStorage userForJID:[message from]
                                                             xmppStream:xmppStream
                                                   managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext_roster]];

    NSString *body = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
    NSString *displayName = [user displayName];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive)
    { 
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:displayName
                                                            message:body
                                                            delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];

    }
    else
    {
        // We are not active, so use a local notification instead
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.alertAction = @"Ok";
        localNotification.fireDate=[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0];
        localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From: %@\n%@",displayName,body];
        NSLog(@"localNotification.alertBody:-%@",localNotification.alertBody);
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
    }
}
}
```

And i want to show that received messages in conversation view (in tableview) which is in an other class.

Here the code which is displaying send messages in tableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell=nil;
cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MessageCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text=[[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"msg"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"You";
cell.textLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
return cell;
}
```

**So, my question is how to take that received messages in array or in dictionary and take that to tableview cell for row at indexpath to show in tableview.**

Comment: use notifier ....and post and add notifier to get data in your tableview controller

Comment: i didn't get it correctly.please can u explain me with code

Comment: I have referred this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844763/ios-xmpp-received-message-in-conversation-screen

Comment: yes you can follow that...In that he used it same way as i told you

Comment: yes i got message in tableview now to allign it left and right...

Comment: for that you need to change the constraints or use different cells for incoming and outgoing

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want to display a chat view between two people ?

I made a `Swift Wrapper` around the `XMPPFramework`, it uses `JSQMessageViewController` for the `UI`.

It will simplify the development of a basic chat app.

You can check it out [here](https://github.com/processone/xmpp-messenger-ios).